# For any elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $E$ is ordinary.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, and fix a Weierstrass equation for $E$ having coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. How do I see that there are infinitely many primes $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that the reduced curve $E/\mathbb{F}_p$ has Hasse invariant $1$?

[Joe Silverman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/317822/joe-silverman) writes the following [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/254520/97565).

> Elkies and Serre have independent proofs that for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a constant $C_\epsilon>0$ such that 
>   $$
> {\#\{p\le X : E/\mathbb{F}_p \text{ is ordinary}\}} \ge C_\epsilon
> X^{3/4-\epsilon}.
> $$

However, I just want to know that there are infinitely many ordinary primes, which should be much easier to see.

Comment: In Joe Silverman's answer to your MO question, he gives a reference to his own well-known textbook on elliptic curves, pointing to an exercise in which a proof of this weaker statement is outlined. Does that not answer your question?

Comment: @DavidLoeffler No because the exercise still seems quite hard to me.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Let me know if the below still seems too hard--I might be able to make it simpler.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Oops, sorry! Wrong person. I guess the OP will be pinged regardless.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to get this off the unanswered list, let me provide a solution to the exercise that Silverman mentions. $\newcommand \Q{\mathbb{Q}}$ $\newcommand \Z{\mathbb{Z}}$ $\newcommand \F{\mathbb{F}}$ $\newcommand \E{\mathcal{E}}$ $\newcommand \p{\mathfrak{p}}$ $\newcommand \h{\mathcal{O}}$

So, let $E/\Q$ be an elliptic curve and let $\E/\Z$ be a minimal Weierstrass model (which exists since $\Q$ has class number $1$). Fix an ancillary prime $\ell$. We claim that if $p$ is a prime satisfying the following:

- $p\geqslant 5$
- $p\nmid\text{Cond}(E)$ (where $\text{Cond}(E)$ is the conductor of $E$)
- $p$ splits completely in $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K:=\mathbb{Q}(E[\ell](\overline{\mathbb{Q}}))$

then $E$ has good ordinary reduction at $p$. This proves the claim since there are infinitely many $p$ satisfying these conditions (there are infinitely many primes that split in $K$ by, applying a hammer to a fly, Cebotarev density and there are only finitely many primes not satisfying the first two conditions).

To see this, let $\p$ be any prime $\mathcal{O}_K$ dividing $p$. Note that $E_K$ has good reduction at $\p$ with, in fact, a model over $(\h_K)_\p$ given by $\E_{(\h_K)_\p}$. Now, note that basic theory (smooth proper base change if we're applying hammers to flies again :P) says that we have an isomorphism $T_\ell E_{K_\p}\cong T_\ell \E_{k(\p)}$ (with $k(\p):= \h_K/\p$) intertwining the surjection $G_{K_\p}\to G_{k(\p)}$. But, note that since $p$ split in $K$ we have that $k(\p)=\F_p$. So, let $\sigma\in G_{K_\p}$ lift $\text{Frob}_p\in G_{\F_p}$. Note then that by our isomorphism if Tate modules we have that $\text{tr}(\sigma)=\text{tr}(\text{Frob}_p)$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}$. But, note that

$$\text{tr}(\sigma)\mod \ell=\text{tr}(\sigma \mod \ell)=\text{tr}(\sigma\mid_{E[\ell]})=\text{tr}(\text{id})=2$$
and thus, evidently, we may conclude that $\text{tr}(\text{Frob}_p)\ne 0$. Since $p\geqslant 5$ this implies that $\E_{\F_p}$ is ordinary as claimed.

Comment: What means $E[l](\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ (or $E[l](k)$) ?

Comment: @user1952009 It just means the $\ell$-torsion points rational over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ (or $k$).

Comment: Nice answer (which I upvoted). By the way, I think one should take $\ell$ to be odd (otherwise $\mathrm{tr}(\sigma) = 2 \pmod{\ell}$ doesn't tell us much if $\ell = 2$).